# Looking for a way to schedule the running of an application on heroku

Tags: heroku, deployment, scheduling

Heroku has a 550-hour free dyno plan which is great but doesn't cover a full month. They offer a way to get 1000 hours, but it requires linking a credit card.

**The problem:**
I want to have my application be 'down/sleeping' eg. not using the hours between certain hours of the day? I can't seem to find a way of doing this? There seems to be some addon's that could potentially do this but they require a credit card to be linked anyways.

Does anyone in the community know a way of scheduling dynos free without having a card linked?

Comment: Heroku does something similar by default: free web dynos go to sleep after 30 minutes of inactivity. They will not consume dyno hours when sleeping. When a request comes in, they'll wake up and start serving your application. The initial response will be a bit slow since your dyno is waking up, but once it's awake it should perform normally. Does that satisfy your needs? See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours#dyno-sleeping

Comment: Unfortunately not as it’s running a discord bot so it needs to already be running to actually receive a wake up command

Comment: I'm not clear on how that's relevant. Does your bot receive HTTP requests or operate some other way?